# Azure Service Bus: 1 client -> 1 queue approach - how to manage dead-letter queues?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In my messaging app I decided to allocate an individual queue for a client. This way routing and security are quite easy. But I can't figure out how to deal with dead-letter queues then (when message expires, let's say). I want to use serverless approach with Azure functions to handle messages from DLQ. It's easy to setup to trigger a function when a message gets placed in a queue. But if I have 1000 clients, that would require 1000 functions?.. From what I can see you can attach a function to a single "trigger" - meaning single queue. Am I missing something here? what's the right approach to uniformly deal with DLQ messages?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure-blog/cross-post-centralized-dead-letter-queue-with-azure-service-bus/ba-p/370708) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is how to deal with thousands of DLQs, one possible solution would be to configure your queues and set [`ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.queueproperties.forwarddeadletteredmessagesto?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-administration-queueproperties-forwarddeadletteredmessagesto) property in each of the queue to point to another queue.

That way the dead-lettered messages from all the queues will go in a single queue and you can attach a Function to that queue for processing of such messages.